# Strange variable behaviour

Tags: php, variables

How is this possible?

```
$post_icon = $_REQUEST['icon'];
if($post_icon == 0)
     var_dump($post_icon);
```

Output:

```
string(15) "icon_smilie.gif"
```

It shouldnt print anything, as `$post_icon` is not equal to `0`.

`string(15) "icon_smilie.gif"` this is my icon (selected by radio input), but I don't know why, it is passing through `0` value.

What is the problem?

Comment: may be some thing wrong with your HTML front end ?? did you double checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On comparison, the string is converted to a number, namely `0`:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

and

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

Use strict comparison `===` instead. It also compares the *type* of the values.

See [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (at the bottom, String conversion to numbers)

Comment: Because it is defined that way.